# ModelAttribute object fields are null in the controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

When i submit my form, the modelAttribute remain null. I looked for my mistake  but i am stuck somewhere in the code and asking for your assistance...  please check the code below

Spring version 4.2.0

```
<form:form class="form-horizontal" modelAttribute="book"
            action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/book/add" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend class="center-block">
                    New Book Information<span style="font-size: small"> * is a
                        required field</span>
                </legend>


                <!-- title -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="title">* Title</label>

                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <form:input type="text" path="title" class="form-control" id="title"
                            required="required" placeholder="Title" />
                        <span class="help-block">Title of the book</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- author -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="author">*
                        Author</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <form:input type="text" path="author" class="form-control" id="author"
                            required="required" placeholder="Author" />
                        <span class="help-block">Author of the book</span>
                    </div>
                </div></form:form>
```

controller:
Get:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addBook(Model model) {
    Book book = new Book();
    model.addAttribute("book", book);
    return "addBook";
}
```

Post:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addBookPost(@ModelAttribute("book") Book book, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println(book.getTitle());
    bookService.save(book);

    MultipartFile bookImage = book.getBookImage();
    System.out.println(book);
    try {
        byte[] bytes = bookImage.getBytes();
        String name = book.getId() + ".png";
        BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(new File("src/main/resources/static/image/book/" + name)));
        stream.write(bytes);
        stream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "redirect:bookList";
}
```

error trace:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
com.adminportal.service.impl.BookServiceImpl.save(BookServiceImpl.java:18)
com.adminportal.controller.BookController.addBookPost(BookController.java:40)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Since i am not getting any data from the form, thats why the object cant be saved in DB. How to bind the form data to controller? i have tried all the solutions as of now and I am not able to figure out where i am wrong, what i have missed out. Kindly help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to change to `addBookPost(@RequestBody Book book`

Comment: Remove `HttpServletRequest request` parameter and retry.

Comment: The fields on book are null? or the Book reference itself is null? you probably have a mismatch between the submitted form and books' fields

Comment: @StanislavL "@RequestBody" is not working. Getting below error
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Comment: @IssamEL-ATIF not working.

Comment: @MosheArad there are no mismatch between model path names and book object fields names ..

Comment: @SajidReshmi this line its executed correctly? System.out.println(book.getTitle());

Comment: @cralfaro no its printing null. Thats what i said, i am getting all the fields in modelAttribute "book" as null

Comment: @SajidReshmi as you are not sending any file in the form, could do you remove the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data"? Just to verify this can be the problem.

Comment: @cralfaro still facing same issue.

Comment: @SajidReshmi change your controller post to String addBookPost(Book book) and check if now send something, also please verify the request post in your browser if its sending the attributes. Inspect the network tab

Comment: @cralfaro why does it work when i modify the definition to String addBookPost(Book book) ???

Comment: @cralfaro when i remove  enctype="multipart/form-data" from the form attributes the application works.. Since in my application i am uploading an image in the jsp form, i need to include this. Any alternate solution???

Comment: fixed it!!! added common-io dependency in pom

Comment: @SajidReshmi great you fixed it, go ahead :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you do have setters defined in the Book object. Because when the JSP is submitted, the details are mapped into the Java Book object through the setters.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the @ModelAttribute from controller part. Ensure that the path attribute on jsp matching with the properties of your model bean (i.e. Book).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addBookPost(Book book, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you have
**java.lang.NullPointerException**
on this line:
**com.adminportal.service.impl.BookServiceImpl.save(BookServiceImpl.java:18)**
maybe you send empty form? It is better to use validation with BindingResult on attribute and check validation form
http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html
or you have
com.adminportal.service.impl.BookServiceImpl = **null**

Comment: book model attribute is null because i have  enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form attributes. I am uploading an image in the form. If i remove enctype attribute, the application works. I cant ignore this attribute, any alternate solution for this?

Comment: what if I want allow null values in the form and set default values in a fields where form is empty. how can I do that?